# genuine emergency / challenge - no image

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, gpu, pci

on a quest to use as much gpu as i possibly could on virtualbox in linux, i followed the instructions on this tutorial, specifically i think it went wrong at this timestamp https://youtu.be/NuXznuDk9NA?t=1431.

i edited grub, changed nvidia drivers and set them to the vfio pci parameters and blocked nouveau from working. after that i rebooted the system and ubuntu wouldn't load, so i turned off the computer mid-boot and tried again. it boots fine, but no image at all... tried booting into the BIOS and there still wasn't any image.

it turns out that nvidia is the only gpu on my pc, so that's pretty much why the image isn't working (i think). anybody here know how to navigate in the dark? i'm guessing i screwed up big time.

Comment: re install from scratch

Comment: I WAS ABLE TO ACCESS THE BIOS. no idea how to proceed though.

Comment: Use live USB as @anlag suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

Use a live boot USB drive to boot the computer, then you can mount the hard drive’s file system and either 1) try to fix your boot/graphics settings, or 2) recover your data before performing a full reinstall. It’s your call but I wouldn’t spend too much time trying to resolve it, a reinstall will often be the most effective option, especially if you don’t really know what you’re doing.

Comment: If you are setting up a GPU passthrough, you need a second GPU for the Ubuntu host, since the NVIDIA GPU that you set up to passthrough to the VM will be dedicated to the VirtualBox guest and will NOT be available for the host anymore! You might be able to undo the vfio settings using a `chroot` from a live boot USB device. Try the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery under the "Update Failure" section to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, you answered fast! Unfortunately I wasn't able to salvage anything from the situation, from the BIOS there weren't really any options for me to undo the stuff I changed and trying to boot the computer from there would result in an endless loading screen.

Even if I could get the exact files I changed to undo them, I'm not sure I'd be able to. If it wasn't clear I am very new to Ubuntu, Linux OS' in general really. So even though I was pretty good at following the instructions, there was no way I'd figure out a way to trace my steps back.

Silver lining? There wasn't much in the hard drive I could lose anyway. I'm on a new PC set up and using it to test different operating systems in and out of virtual machines, mostly seeing how much they can handle. I set my primary Os as Ubuntu because it's light and boots pretty fast even on a brand new install.

I was mostly worried that this might do damage to the NVIDIA card itself, because I have never seen anyone do something like this before. I loaded up another Ubuntu OS, the LTS version this time, and it's working fine, better even.

What I've learned from this? do NOT mess with boot files, unless it's within a GUI programmed by people smart enough to realise how bad things can end otherwise, or you are already well learned in such matters.

Thanks to everyone who replied, expect to see me asking questions around here often!

also would've been fun to try and figure a way to navigate without video...

...probably would not have worked.